# Cant run shell script in PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

When I am trying to run shell script with `exec` and `shell_exe` nothing happens!
When I run with those command `ls` or `whoami` all work's.

What could it be?

Comment: Please add an example of how you're trying to run it.

Comment: Have you tried a fully qualified PATH (EX: "/usr/local/myscript")?

Comment: Thank's for the answers..  i tried: **exec('users/ig/..../script.sh')**, also **shell_exec('users/ig/..../script.sh')** and                **exec('sh users/ig/..../script.sh')**                                     nothing didn't help. when i trying **echo exec('whoami')** it\' working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you echo the output?

```
echo exec('ls');
```

Do you have safe_mode enabled?

```
phpinfo();
```

When yes: (from the manual)

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed
>   to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Try to call exec with

```
exec('...pathtoyourbashscript...', $out, $return);
```

Then

```
echo $return;
```

If it shows `127` it´s likely that the path is wrong.

Also check the permissions. User 'nobody' is probably the apache user, which needs the rights to access and execute the script.

You can change the permissions by running

`chmod 755 pathtouyourscript`

This means something like 'I don't mind if other people read or run this file, but only I should be able to modify it'.

Comment: The `echo exec('ls');` is working good. I checked with  `phpinfo()` and its shows that the **safe mode is off**. On Configure Command i saw **'--enable-safe-mode'**

Comment: Its returns **1**. if its helps, when i check who is the user (whoami) it show's **nobody**.

Comment: try to `chmod 755 pathtouyourscript`

Comment: What is the shell file doing you try to execute? Maybe there are permission relevant tasks the user 'nobody' can´t execute...

Comment: The shell script create directory by checking the file name and set the name for the directory, then copy the file to that directory and delete it form original.

Comment: Ok, than try to `chmod 777 -R` all directories to which the scripts writes. But consider that this gives write-access to every user.

Comment: I think i get the problem, but need some help...I created a new script and tart exec it, started with `echo` command-worked! creating dir with `mkdir`- worked! moving files with `mv`- worked! But it doesn't exec those lines(works if you ran it in terminal): `for FILE in *.{png,html} mv "$FILE" /users/.....; done`  WHAT'S WRONG WITH THAT?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, check to make sure that the Apache user has the required permissions to execute the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to figure out if the function has been disabled with `disable_functions`.

```
$exec = new ReflectionFunction('exec');
print $exec->isDisabled() ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program is web based i.e. for linux, Try making a php file to process the shell.
and a shell file to handle the php..

For instance: runAllShell.php file can contain a loop.:

```
<?php
// Developed by A T.
// Count the files
$directory = '/put/directory/path_here/';
$files = glob($directory . '*.*');

if ( $files !== false )
{
    $filecounter = count( $files );

}
else
{
    echo "No Files were found";
}
$fileCount = $filecounter;

// Start the index
$fileNumber = 1;
while($fileNumber <= fileCount){
shell_exec('$fileNumber . ".sh"');
// get some feedback
echo "The ".$fileNumber." file has been excecuted";
// increment file number
$fileNumber++;

}
?>
```

make sure that all the .sh files in the directory are numericaly ordered for this to work i.e: 1.sh 2.sh 3.sh and so on.

Best regards,
AT.